# global name 'hidden' is not defined

Tags: python, state, hidden

Here is my code, can't figure out why the hidden state is not working.

```
self.Z1 = self.facecanvas.create_text(1050,100,text="Z",state=hidden,font=("Comic Sans MS",120, 'bold'))
```

Comment: maybe adding some quotes will help

Comment: Why did you think it would be defined?

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very little detail about the problem. Here's my take on it however.

You have answered your question in the title of this post. If you notice you're passing the argument `state=hidden` to the `create_text()` method. In python values are either a string or a variable that you already defined somewhere. You have passed the variable "hidden" to this function and not defined it as anything. I suspect that you meant to use `state='hidden'` instead. This assumes that this function understands that `state` can be the value `'hidden'`. With so little context into what you're doing and what this is, it's hard to give more help than this.

I certainly hope this helps.